# How to change parse(change) KeyName in object?

Tags: typescript

i want to parse Object by Chaning keyname.
but i have trouble with " Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'keyof SignInStore' can't be used to index type '{}' " Error

```
interface SignInStore {
  storeId:number,
  storeName:string,
  email:string,
  destinationName:string,
  primaryPhone:string,
}
```

```
const signInStore = response.data;
        const parseSignInStore:SignInStore = Object.keys(signInStore).reduce((parseStore,param) => {
          let newParamName:keyof SignInStore;
          switch(param){
            case 'id':
              newParamName = 'storeId';
              break
            case 'name':
              newParamName = 'storeName';
              break
            case 'destination_name':
              newParamName = 'destinationName';
              break
            case 'primary_phone':
              newParamName = 'primaryPhone';
              break
            case 'email':
              newParamName = 'email';
              break
            default:
              newParamName = param;
          }
          parseStore[newParamName] = signInStore[param]
          return parseStore
        },{})
        setSignInStore(parseSignInStore);
        setIsSignedIn(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to accumulator in your code

```
...
,{} as Record<keyof SignInStore, any>)
```

Comment: do you mind upvoting it as well please :D?